# Calculation of triple integral over an elliptic cone

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The task at hand is to calculate the following integral: $$I=\iiint_V z^2\,dx\,dy\,dz$$where$$V=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3:\,\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}\le\frac{z^2}{c^2},\, 0\le z\le h\}$$
Using the transformation: $$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x=au \\ 
y=bv \\
z=cw
\end{array}
\right.$$
I got:$$I=\iiint_{V'} w^2\,du\,dv\,dw$$where$$V'=\{(u,v,w)\in\mathbb R^3:\,u^2+v^2\le w^2,\, 0\le w\le \frac{h}{c}\}$$
but, after that, using spherical coordinates will complicate matters, in my opinion, as I won't be able to know all of the limits for each new variable.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you forgot the $c$ in your substitution in the integrand, and the Jacobian determinant. The integral becomes
$$I=abc^3\iiint_{V'} w^2\,du\,dv\,dw$$

The integration region is the upper half of a cone. Then the limits of $w$ are just $0$ and $h/c$. Using cylindrical coordinate $u=r\cos\theta, v=r\sin\theta, w=w$ would solve it.

Comment: You're right about the constants, I forgot them when copying them from my paper sheet. Thanks for the answer. For some reason, I was stuck at switching to spherical coordinates.